# Select option submit on change Rails4

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, ruby-on-rails-4

Im making a code that auto submit a form after selecting an option. The submit button   is hidden on the form.Im usign ajax in the form so the updates is going to reander in the same page. any help will be grateful.

view.html.erb

```
<tbody>
    <% @complaints.each do |complaint| %>
       <tr>
        <td id="priority">
          <%= bootstrap_form_for complaint do |p| %>
            <%= p.select(:priority,[['Selecione Nivel'],['Nivel Alto', {:class=>'btn-danger'}],['Nivel Mediano', {:class=>'btn-warning'}],['Nivel Bajo', {:class=>'btn-primary'}]])%>
            <%= p.submit 'Update', :class => "btn" %>
           <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= complaint.id %>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Html Output

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/complaints/4" class="edit_complaint" id="edit_complaint_4" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Buscar"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Buscar"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="E8gNdFLaMhswXNo3rUk/j875u5rk8j2Gx+NM9zGWrTA=" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Buscar"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="complaint_priority">Priority</label><div class="select2-container form-control" id="s2id_complaint_priority"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-3">Selecione Nivel</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen3" class="select2-offscreen">PriorityPriorityPriority</label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-3" id="s2id_autogen3"><div class="select2-drop select2-display-none">   <div class="select2-search select2-search-hidden select2-offscreen">       <label for="s2id_autogen3_search" class="select2-offscreen">PriorityPriorityPriority</label>       <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-3" id="s2id_autogen3_search" placeholder="">   </div>   <ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-3">   </ul></div></div><select class="form-control select2-offscreen" id="complaint_priority" name="complaint[priority]" tabindex="-1" title="PriorityPriorityPriority"><option value="Selecione Nivel">Selecione Nivel</option>
<option class="btn-danger" value="Nivel Alto">Nivel Alto</option>
<option class="btn-warning" value="Nivel Mediano">Nivel Mediano</option>
<option class="btn-primary" value="Nivel Bajo">Nivel Bajo</option></select></div>
            <input class="btn form-control input-sm" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update" placeholder="Buscar">
</form>
```

My jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery.fn.submitOnChange = function() {
  this.find('input[type=submit]').remove();
  this.find('input[type=select]').change(function() {
  $(this).parents('form').submit();
  });
  return this;
}

$(function() {
  $('.edit_complaint').submitOnChange();
    });
});

This code hide the but dont submit.
```

Comment: Is your select element a child of a form element? And, are you looking to submit the form via ajax or via default form submission.

Comment: via ajax with the remote: true   and the jquery in the assets file complaints.js. this form is for updating the status of a complaint priority(High,Med,Low).

Comment: Once the ajax request completes, what element would you like to update? I can give you a solution right away but I'd have to as for the content (HTML) your server sends to your browser -- that's what jQuery would act on.

Comment: You want the html output???

Comment: Yes, minimal HTML; `form`, `select` elements and where you'd like to output your status to -- what `html` element.

Comment: Check the post I add the code
in Railcast #136 jQuery & Ajax 
hi use this code for making the submit hide and the checkbox auto submit.
jQuery.fn.submitOnCheck = function() {
  this.find('input[type=submit]').remove();
  this.find('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
  });
  return this;
}

$(function() {
  $('.edit_task').submitOnCheck();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should submit the form upon `select` change. Since I do not know your logic pertaining to updating the status of a complaint priority, you would have to tweak the statement in the success handler, `$('.status-selector').html( data );` to suit your needs:

```
$(function() {
    $('form.edit_complaint').on('submit',function() {
        var url = this.action,
            data = $(this).serialize(),
            method = this.method.toUpperCase();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            success: function( data ) {
                $('.status-selector').html( data );
            }
        });
    });
    $('form.edit_complaint').find('select').on('change',function() {
        $('form.edit_complaint').triggerHandler( 'submit' );
    });
});
```

Comment: this code looks great ill try it out and let you know. thanks for your time.

Comment: The pleasure was mine. Just let me know how I can be further assistance.